# A Pigeon house or something else?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Is there a word meaning a place where pigeons are kept and held?
In the Middle East, some people have a place on their roof to keep pigeons. Sometimes, this place is like a big cage and sometimes it is made from other building materials such bricks, cement, etc.

A person that has made this place is called **pigeon-fancier**.

A literal rendering of this place is **pigeon house**.

Have you heard this word in English?
And is there another word for it?

Comment: I think it would generally be referred to as a [*pigeon coop*](http://www.aaronmchugh.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/3821041425_225cf6b95d.jpg).

Comment: Yes I have heard this word in English. There was an outbuilding near the house where I grew up (in upstate New York, USA) that we always called the pigeon house.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, "pigeon coop" is the most common term (even though the dictionaries appear to prefer "pigeon loft" or "pigeon house").  "Coop" is most familiar because a place for keeping chickens is a [chicken coop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_coop).

Comment: In the UK *Pigeon Loft* will tend to be used to refer to a modern structure of timber or profiled metal sheeting, used by someone who keeps racing pigeons.

Answer (score 3):

Try [***dovecote***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22dovecote%22&biw=522&bih=343&prmd=ismvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPjbvgxMjMAhVDBBoKHbSEAw0Q_AUIBigB&dpr=2)

> A small house or box for pigeons to live in,
>
> cote: a shed or coop for small domestic animals and especially pigeons
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dovecote)

Also, ***columbarium*** or ***columbary***

> A structure for keeping doves or pigeons; a dovecote or pigeon loft.
>
> [-Ologies & -Isms.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/columbary)

Comment: Fun fact: Where cremated ashes are entombed in slots in a wall, it's called a *columbarium* because of the resemblance to the openings in a dovecot. However, it also denotes people being buried in columns.

Comment: 'Dovecote' (In Scotland, 'Doocot') is generally, in the UK, used to refer to an historic structure, usually stone built. Modern pigeon homes in less durable materials are 'pigeon lofts'.

Comment: Uh, in the US, at least, a *columbarium* is a structure for holding the urns of cremated people.

Answer (score 2):

Historians (UK) prefer **dovecotes**  to name the tall buildings of brick or stone (or even timber and plaster) with nesting holes for hundreds of birds. Pigeons lay eggs for most of the Spring and Summer so eggs and squabs provided food.  But the main economic reason was the dung, high in nitrogen and phosphates,

[[image: Dovecote with lantern ]]

**Dovecote** today is the word for a garden ornament. The doves will usually be white doves or fantails.
[image]

> Welsh Dovecotes - Wall mounted Dovecote for sale

[image: Wall-mounted cote]

Those who keep **tumblers** to watch their flight and hold aerobatic competitions may simply call their home a **box,** or the **box** 
http://www.feathersite.com/Poultry/Pigeons/Tumblers/BRKDutchTumbler.html
download

[image: tumbler]

If the birds are kept for their plumage, they will usually be housed in an **aviary.**  This photo accompanied an advertisement: "selling due to lose of mate + i need to remove the aviary."
[image]

**Loft** or **Pigeon Loft** is the word used by most pigeon fanciers especially those who keep racing- / homing-pigeons, even if they are housed in a shed at ground-level.

[image]

http://www.pigeonracingpigeon.com/whats-new/loft-construction-and-design/

Answer (score 1):

***[Pigeonry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pigeonry):***

> - (Architecture) a loft for keeping pigeons in; dovecote; pigeon house

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Maybe it's different in the UK, but in the US "pigeonry" would mainly get you dumb looks.

Comment: @Hotlicks Nope. Same in UK. No doubt the word *exists,* but it's hardly common. (It does have the same form as *canonry* or *archdeaconry* for the houses of ecclesiastical dignitaries, so it might be understood; but it's not well-used.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - So, generally speaking, an "XXXonry" is a place for strange birds?